# Returning Multiple Values from a Custom Function

Tags: ms-access, vba

So, I've got a ValidateForm function that loops through a form to validate each control.  I have a collection set up called ValData to capture different bits of info to be passed out of the function.  This is working great.

However, I don't know how to access each item in ValData after the function returns.  I can get one at a time like: ValidateForm().IsValid, but in order to get each item, I have to run the function again.  I want to avoid this.

Is there a way to run the function once, but access the values of each item returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending upon your requirements (which are NOT clear in your question!  ;-)  ), you might consider using a Collection as the return from your function:

```
Private Function MyResultsFunction() As Collection
    Dim output As Collection
    Set output = New Collection

    'Hydrate your collection with data by whatever means necessary:
    With output

        'Stupid example code:
        .Add "Item1"
        .Add "Item2"
        .Add "Item3"
        .Add "Item4"
    End With

    'Return a reference to the collection as the function output:
    Set MyResultsFunction = output

End Function
```

As a simple, retarded test of the above:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    'A variable to receive the results from your function:
    Dim Results As Collection

    'An iterator to loop through the results contained in the collection:
    Dim CurrentItem As Variant

    'For this example, a string to toss the results into to display in the
    'MsgBox:
    Dim output As String

    'Use the local Collection defined above to access the reference returned by
    'your function:
    Set Results = MyResultsFunction

    'Iterate through the collection and do something with the results
    'per your project requirements:
    For Each CurrentItem In Results

        'This is stupid example code:
        output = output & CurrentItem & vbCrLf
    Next

    'I am just displayng the results to show that it worked:
    MsgBox output

    'Clean up:
    Set Results = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hope that heps!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to say what exactly you are tyring to do, but here is one of several ways you can store results to query later.

Declare a public variable at the top of your module to represent the items from your ValData function. After you populate the array, you can access the items through a normal function.

You obviously could do more sophisticated things, especially if you use a collection object. You could even store a counter and create a GetNext() function. I hope this gives you a heads start.

```
Public Results(1 To 2) As String

Sub CreateTestArray()
    Results(1) = "Foo"
    Results(2) = "Bar"
End Sub

Function GetResult(ByVal i As Long) As String
    If i <= UBound(Results) Then
        GetResult = Results(i)
    End If
End Function

Sub ProofOfConcept()
    MsgBox GetResult(2) ' will show "Bar"
End Sub
```